# Is there an Atom editor plugin similar to VSCode Great Icons?

Tags: visual-studio-code, atom-editor

The editor Visual Studio Code have a plugin called "VSCode Great Icons" that when you work with a node project, you can see an icon different depending on different file type (icon for js, ts, .gitignore, etc).

I would like ask if there is a similar plugin in the atom editor, so we can see in projects like angular, o nodejs, an icon at the left to each file depending of the file type.

Comment: You might want to look at https://atom.io/packages/file-icons

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Dan mentions in his comment above, [`file-icons`](https://atom.io/packages/file-icons) is a good place to start (it's the package I use).

There are others too, including [`file-type-icons`](https://atom.io/packages/file-type-icons), which uses monochrome icons, and [`seti-icons`](https://atom.io/packages/seti-icons), which appears to use the icons from the SETI UI theme.

There are probably others too; try searching Atom's package directory.